# Headphone/microphone only working when partially plugged into the splitter

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I had a pair of headphones with a microphone that worked fine on this computer a month ago. But they stopped working and while troubleshooting, I discovered that the audio and microphone would work when it was partially plugged in. But it would pop in and out and wasn't reliable.

I assumed it was a hardware issue and got a brand new pair of different headphones (with a new splitter) and I'm having the same issue right out of the box.

Both have a single cable running to a splitter for separate mic and headphone jacks. When I unplug the splitter and plug the headphones directly into the audio out, it works fine.

Comment: what exactly is your question? ...sounds like a wrong type of splitter

Comment: You need to accurately describe [& photograph] the components. "A splitter" really tells us absolutely nothing about your connectivity.

Comment: Is your splitter something like this? -> https://i.imgur.com/AMFu8GW.png

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the audio jack on your computers is broken.  There are metal pins inside of them that are used for both making electrical connections and for holding the jack in.  Poorly made one can get bent, which causes the male end to pop out and/or make a bad connection.

The easiest thing to do is go wireless or buy a USB audio headset.  It is possible to replace the jack on the motherboard by someone who knows how to solder.  However, since you can permanently damage your computer if you do not know what you are doing, its not worth it.

Comment: Thanks but the audio jack works fine when I'm not using the splitter. And again, I don't think it's the splitter because I just bought a new one and they're both having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the issue is not due to a faulty connector, then it is likely that the splitter you are using is not correct for or compatible with either or both your computer or your headphone jack or it is poorly designed.

TRS connectors have several variations that *should* allow compatibility between the various types. This will include simple headphones, headphones with microphones, stereo vs mono, etc. Each of these configurations require different sets of signals, and you'll notice the connector for each of these will have a different number of sections on them.

The fact this works when the headphone jack is only partially inserted indicates the splitter is poorly designed or incompatible, and this "partial connection" is the point inside that splitter where the connections are correct.